# Combo box to open Form

Tags: ms-access

How can i use combo box or drop down list to open another form? I wanted to select the option from combo box or drop down list and it will open specific form based on which of the option that I clicked.

Thank You

Comment: Assuming the form name is the bound column of the combo or list then simply `DoCmd.OpenForm Me.YourComboBoxName` should work

Comment: Thank you, is this the full code?

Comment: @RidhwanZ. You have asked an incomplete question and expecting full code. The hint is already given.

Comment: Add the code shown to the after update or OnChange event of the combo.

Comment: Thank you @Minty , it really worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Open specific forms with macro:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add & Name Combo Box SelectFormsEdit

Go to `Property Sheet` `->` `Data Tab` `->` `Edit Row Source` `->` `SQL`:

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((MsysObjects.Type)=-32768));
```

`Event Tab`, `After Update`, ... `Code Builder`:

```
Private Sub SelectFormsEdit_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.OpenForm SelectFormsEdit, , , , acFormEdit
End Sub
```